# Apache Camel Concept Data format vs Data type

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel. While I have an idea about the following concepts, would like to get a clear understanding  of the following concepts. Yes, I have gone through Apache Camel documentation.

1. Data Format conversion
2. Data Type conversion
3. Marshalling and Unmarshalling

What I am looking for is a clear conceptual differentiation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Camel in Action books cover these concepts in much details. Otherwise there is only the regular Camel website and javadoc as documentation.

Comment: Thanks Claus..I read that in the book..Still bit confused about the conceptual differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These terms have a lot of different meaning in programming and computers in general. Additionally, across Camel components the terms Data Format and Data Type may be used interchangeably.

1. Data Format -- typically the format of "data on the wire". This is like Text, or binary for file handling and messaging scenarios (.txt, .csv, .bin, JMS, MQTT, STOMP, etc).. or JSON and XML for REST and SOAP web services (generally over http)
2. Data Type -- totally overloaded.. in Camel, (I'll risk being flamed for this..).. it generally has a meaning of what Java class is used as the input or output to a component. Camel also has a ton of auto-type conversion routines, so some of the subtle differences go unnoticed by users. For example, consuming from a JMS queue.. may generate a javax.jms.TextMessage, but the next step may use a java.lang.String class. Camel can auto-convert between those types.
3. Marshalling and Unmarshalling is the step in converting from Java Class -> Data Format and Data Format -> Java Class. For example, a JSON payload would be *unmarshalled* to a com.bobtire.Order Java class and used by a Java processor in Camel. Conversely, after doing some processing, one may need to *marshall* a com.bobtire.Order Java class to JSON to send to a REST endpoint. These functions are handled by "data format" modules within Camel. Common ones: JSON, JAXB (for XML), Bindy, PGP and JCE (for encryption)

Comment: @SRaj great!  Will you please 'Accept' the answer ?

Comment: SRaj: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers   There should be an "Accept" link next to the answer.  Oh.. click the Check mark below the vote up / down icons

Comment: Done, Thanks Matt!

Comment: Much appreciated =)